# Select position on a car image in a modal. Should be divided in 6 divs

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I have a customer project. The customer can select a car and then choose where the damage is located on the picture, which is divided into 6 parts.

How can I do that? I thought I could solve it with z-index but it doesn't seem to work for me.

if you look at the second picture (expected look). You can see that the car is divided into 6 corners. These should be, for example, 6 divs that I can select. How do I get these 6 divs above the picture.

That's how it looks at the moment:
[image: current look]

```
      <fieldset class="form-group col-lg-12">
        <label class="font-medium-2 text-bold-600" for="car">Auto</label>

        <ng-select formControlName="car" [searchable]="false" [clearable]="false" [items]="allCars"
          bindLabel="name" bindValue="val">
        </ng-select>

        <img class="col-lg-12" [src]="this.GutachtenForm.value.car" />
      </fieldset>
```

What I want to do:
[image: expected look]

The user should be able to select the positions and these are then be marked.

Comment: you question is not clear. Please provide more information.

Comment: Roughly speaking, I have a picture that I want to divide into 6 parts and can then select these when I click with the mouse, this part is highlighted in green.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Make sure to get your result like this as I have mentioned in the URL
```

http://jsfiddle.net/eg5o1w6L/1/

```
Once you have an individual div, You can write your hover logic for that div.
```

Comment: I need it as <img class="col-lg-12" [src]="this.GutachtenForm.value.car" />